# Need Solution. 2 row into 1 row sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my 2 normalize table which has Clientid into Telephone table

```
(ClientID int Primary key,
FName varchar(25),
LName varchar(25),
HomeAddress varchar(50))

CREATE TABLE Telephone
(TelephoneID tinyint IDENTITY(1,1)Primary key,
TelephoneNo int,
ClientID int foreign key references Client(ClientID))
```

so the values for my Client table..

```
ClientID | FName  | LName |  HomeAddress   
    1      marvin    Biu    p.guevarra st. 
    2      harry    sendon     cali st.
```

and into my Telephone table..

```
 TelephoneID | TelephoneNo | ClientID  
        1        1234567        1
        2        7654321        1
        3        2222222        2
```

since it is possible to that a client has a multiple telephone no
so i would like to become like this..

```
ClientID | FName  | LName |  HomeAddress   |   Telephones
    1      marvin    Biu    p.guevarra st.   1234567, 7654321
    2      harry    sendon     cali st.          2222222
```

i only come up with the code like this

```
select distinct lname, CAST(telephoneno AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + CAST(telephoneno AS VARCHAR(10)) as Telephones
from telephone
left join client
on client.clientid = telephone.clientid
```

ended up like this..

```
 LName |   Telephones
 Biu      1234567, 1234567
 Biu      7654321, 7654321
 sendon     2222222
```

Please anyone help, its ok that the table ended up in a simple form like above shown,
i really wanted the 1234567 telephoneno join with 7654321 telephoneno with coma in between in telephones column with one Lname "Biu" column. thats make 1 row. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  lname,
  Telephones = STUFF((SELECT ','+ CAST(t.telephoneno AS VARCHAR(10)) 
  FROM telephone t
  WHERE t.clientid  = c.clientid 
  For XML PATH('')
  ),1,1,'')
FROM client c
```

Comment: can you please explain me how you do it and what is xml path and t and c that you put?

Comment: @MharveenBiu. FOR XML, this is how you get concatenated strings : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922(v=sql.110).aspx . t and c just table alias

Answer (score 0):

Always qualify your tables in a join, it makes it much clearer to see what's going on:

```
select distinct t.lname, CAST(t.telephoneno AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + CAST(c.telephoneno AS VARCHAR(10)) as Telephones
from telephone t
left join client c
on c.clientid = t.clientid
```